# Android - start view animation right after activity load is complete

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I ve been trying to find out what callback should I use in order to be absolutely sure that all loading of starting an activity has finished and it's now a good time to start an animation of my views. However only thing I have found is half-measures and not always working solutions. It can't be possible that Android has not provided a solutions for this basic need.

- I've tried onEnterAnimationComplete() but this doesn't get called on some Samsung devices (thnx again Samsung)
- I've tried onWindowFocusChanged()...Animation gets cut in half
- I've tried adding a globalLayoutListener to some view...same thing
- I've tried onResume()...same thing again
- I've tried someView.post(new Runnable(){....}); no luck

Can anyone share their insight ?

Answer (score 2):

try `OnPreDrawListener` that get's called immediatly before the system executes calls on `View.draw(Canvas)`.

I've used a few times for animation, and I saw [Chet Haase](https://plus.google.com/+ChetHaase) suggest it several times on a Q&A.

```
public void MyAct extends AppCompatActivity implements OnPreDrawListener {

  @Override 
  public void onCreate(SavedInstanceState state) {
     super.onCreate(state);
     init all your stuff...

     if(state == null) {
        rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(this);
     }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPreDraw() {
     // remove the listener, you don't want to get called anymore
     rootView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

     do your thing here ...

     return true; // if you return false, it will cancel the draw operation.
  }
}
```

Comment: same thing happens. just like in the other methods it works only if i set a delay fore the animation. if i start it with zero delay i never see it happen